# Странная ошибка Delphi при установлении связи с OpenOffice, функция CreateOleObject

Tags: delphi, open-office

В Delphi 7 пытаюсь установить связь проекта с OpenOffice.
Пишет что неизвестная функция CreateOleObject.
Но нажимаю Ctrl-F1 - и оказывается, что в Помощи она есть, то есть неизвестной она быть не может
Это при том, что этот фрагмент кода писал даже не я, а скопировал форума, где его автора многократно благодарили
В чем же дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю, вы забыли в `uses` добавить модуль `OleAuto`.